# Looking for decimal to alphanumeric number base converter library in Visual Basic (or pseudo code algorithm) WITHOUT recursion

Tags: vb.net, decimal, number-formatting, alphanumeric

I'm looking for a decimal to alphanumeric number base converter library in Visual Basic that does not use recursion.

I found:
http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/07/20/when-hexadecimal-is-not-enough.aspx

which includes a demo app but discovered that it uses recursion. The problem with it using recursion became apparent when I attempted to integrate the library into my own Visual Studio Express 2010 Visual Basic project: I got a stack overflow exception.

Now I could consider increasing the size memory allocated for the stack but it might be hard to determine what this would be, given that the recursion depth might vary depending on the value to be converted.

My situation requires a reliable deterministic solution so I would prefer to discount the idea of using recursion.

I shall do more research and endeavour to write the algorithm from scratch but would rather not re-invent the wheel if it already exists so hence this question. A search on here did not quite give me what I was looking for.

Can you point me in the direction of an existing non-recursive decimal to alphanumeric converter library in Visual Basic?

Comment: It has a link to this (not checked if it uses recursion): http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/19316

Comment: +1 @assylias thanks it looks promising, checking it now...

Comment: Yup, looks recursion-free :) I've had a look through, it's not the most readable code and VB using the function name as return value can mislead but yes, appears to be recursion free. So Now I'm going to integrate it into my Visual Studio 2010 Express Visual Basic project and test it out. I will report back and after that, if OK @assylias, if you then provide this as an Answer I should be able to accept it and upvote it.

Comment: If you manage to get it to work, post your code as an answer, it will be better than just a link ;)

Comment: +1 again @assylias, I will try, But I'd like you to take the credit: all you would have to do is post your same comment as the answer (which I would upvote and accept). BUT Don't do this just yet - once I find the code to work I will let you know to go ahead. I'm a working to a tight deadline so later on today might have some results...

Comment: But I see your point: It will need a bit of modification to work as a class in Visual Studio Express 2010 Visual Basic. Mainly just because of how variables and functions are declared, the main bulk of the code should remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution I provide myself appears to work - so simple too! But that's because it is a one-way conversion; the other libraries aim to be two-way conversion, back and forth between difference bases - but I don't need both ways.

```
Public Class BaseConverter


    Public Shared Function ConvertToBase(num As Integer, nbase As Integer) As String

        Dim retval = ""

        Dim chars As String = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

        ' check if we can convert to another base
        If (nbase  chars.Length) Then
            retval = ""
        End If

        Dim r As Integer

        Dim newNumber As String = ""

        ' in r we have the offset of the char that was converted to the new base
        While num >= nbase
            r = num Mod nbase
            newNumber = chars(r) & newNumber

            'use: num = Convert.ToInt32(num / nbase)
            '(if available on your system)
            'otherwise:
            num = num \ nbase
            ' notice the back slash \ - this is integer division, i.e the calculation only reports back the whole number of times that
            ' the divider will go into the number to be divided, e.g. 7 \ 2 produces 3 (contrasted with 7 / 2 produces 3.5, 
            ' float which would cause the compiler to fail the compile with a type mismatch)
        End While

        ' the last number to convert
        newNumber = chars(num) & newNumber

        Return newNumber
    End Function


End Class
```

I created the above code in Visual Basic based on the C# code in the following link:

CREDIT: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/5babf71f-4375-40aa-971a-21c1f0b9762b/
("convert from decimal(base-10) to alphanumeric(base-36)")

```
public String ConvertToBase(int num, int nbase)
{
    String chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    // check if we can convert to another base
    if(nbase  chars.Length)
        return "";

    int r;
    String newNumber = "";

    // in r we have the offset of the char that was converted to the new base
    while(num >= nbase)
    {
        r = num % nbase;
        newNumber = chars[r] + newNumber;
        num = num / nbase;
    }
    // the last number to convert
    newNumber = chars[num] + newNumber;

    return newNumber;
}
```

@assylias I couldn't get [devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/19316](http://devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/19316) to work - I got the wrong value back. Thanks though for the suggestion.

There is no evidence that it works. I adjusted some declarations and superficial structure of the code to get it to build successfully in Visual Studio Express 2010 Visual Basic. Then stepped through the code in the Visual Studio Express 2010 Visual Basic debugger, the code is hard to follow: variable names not obvious, no comments as to why it is doing what it is doing. From what I understood it was doing, it did not seem like it should be doing that to do the base conversion.