# vb.net convert number to alphanumeric equivalent

Tags: vb.net

I need to convert a four digit number to a three digit alphanumeric number where

001-999 = 001-999
1000 = 00A
1027 = 01A

etc.. up to whatever = ZZZ

I am very new to programming and cannot figure out how to proceed with this issue. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: What you are looking is a [converter from Base 10 to Base 36](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736451/looking-for-decimal-to-alphanumeric-number-base-converter-library-in-visual-basi)

Comment: Even if you are new to programming you should know what kind of numbers you are working with. Who said that you should convert them? That person should explain you _how_.

Comment: @Mike -- If 1000 is 00A then 1026 would be 01A and 1027 would be 01B, right?

Comment: @TimSchmelter -- I think the question is pretty clear.

Comment: @Mike -- What should happen if the result would be greater than `ZZZ`?  Does it throw an exception?

Comment: @the_lotus -- That's not correct, because 1000 doesn't convert to 00A in base 36.

Comment: @roryap: even if it's clear to you the requirement seems not to be that clear to OP which is strange. Nobody would told him "convert 1000  to 00A" without further explanations.

Comment: OK I am trying to make a serial number generator to print bar codes. The serial number must be 3 digits. The serial numbers will range from
0-999

Comment: explained better:
I am making bar codes with a serial number that is 3 digits. The serial # is being generated by a Zebra printer automatically in this range:

001-999
00A-ZZZ

If I print 400 labels today I get 001-400. If I decide to print more I need to know to start at 401.  My problem is if I had printed 1000 labels the last serial would be 00A and I need to start with 00B the next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does this work for you?

```
Private Function ConvertMyNumber(toConvert As UShort) As String
    Const MaxValueToConvert = 3885S
    If (toConvert > MaxValueToConvert) Then Throw New ArgumentException(String.Format("Argument value of {0} exceeds maximum possible value of {1}.", toConvert, MaxValueToConvert))
    Const NumeringSchemeThreshold = 1000
    Const TotalResultLength = 3
    Const PaddingChar = "0"c
    If (toConvert < NumeringSchemeThreshold) Then Return toConvert.ToString().PadLeft(TotalResultLength, PaddingChar)
    Dim adjustedValue = (toConvert - NumeringSchemeThreshold) 'since we're starting with this numbering scheme at NumeringSchemeThreshold
    Const NumbersInAlphabet = 26
    Dim moddedValue = (adjustedValue Mod NumbersInAlphabet) '0 to NumbersInAlphabet - 1 based on the cycle
    Dim numCycles = Fix(adjustedValue / NumbersInAlphabet) 'What "cycle number" it is, i.e. the number of times around the alphabet loop.
    Dim suffix As String = String.Empty
    Dim prefix As String = CStr(numCycles)
    Const firstStepThreshold = 100
    Const secondStepThreshold = 110
    Const LastAlphabetChar = "Z"c

    If (numCycles >= firstStepThreshold And numCycles < secondStepThreshold) Then
        numCycles = numCycles - firstStepThreshold
        prefix = CStr(numCycles)
        suffix = LastAlphabetChar
    ElseIf (numCycles >= secondStepThreshold) Then
        numCycles = numCycles - secondStepThreshold
        suffix = LastAlphabetChar & LastAlphabetChar
        prefix = String.Empty
    End If

    Const AsciiCharValueOffset = 65

    'concat the cycle number to the converted modded letter, and return the zero-padded result.
    Return (prefix & CChar(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(moddedValue + AsciiCharValueOffset)) & suffix).PadLeft(TotalResultLength, PaddingChar)
End Function
```

Comment: This code is working great with any value <=3,599</br>

3,599 converts to 99Z

when I try to convert 3,600 the result = 100A

Comment: now that I accepted your answer do I need to repost the question to get help with this code breaking at 3,599?

Comment: @Mike -- hang on, I'll take a look.

Comment: @Mike, just so I'm clear 3,600 should result in `0AZ`, right?

Comment: @Mike -- Okay I've modified the code.  It should hopefully work for you now.